# How to disable scrolling on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm trying to disable scrolling on a web page when an user open a popup (but he can scroll it).

The popup element has following attributes:

```
#popup {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
    overflow: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And when the user opening a popup, the following code is called:

```
$('#popup').show();
$('html').attr('style', 'overflow: hidden;');
$('body').attr('style', 'overflow: hidden; position: relative;');
```

This solution perfectly work on a desktop browser, but unfortunatly not on mobile.

On mobile, it always possible to scroll (but the scroll speed is slow).

How can I disable also scrolling on mobile browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change body `position` to `fixed`. That will disable the scroll.

Comment: Thanks but I can't, I want to keep the body scrolling and fixed position reset it.

Comment: But try that only for the state when popup is on? Or but an overlay between Body and Popup, that will be fixed, so the "scroll" will pretty much do nothing.